# How to check that a ResultSet contains a specifically named field?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Having `rs`, an instance of java.sql.ResultSet, how to check that it contains a column named "theColumn"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine  if the column name exist in the ResultSet ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599861/how-can-i-determine-if-the-column-name-exist-in-the-resultset)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check to see if a column name exists in a CachedRowSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462534/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-column-name-exists-in-a-cachedrowset)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/class-use/ResultSetMetaData.html) to iterate through the `ResultSet` columns and see if the column name matches your specified column name.

Example:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

// get the column names; column indexes start from 1
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
    String columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
    // Get the name of the column's table name
    if ("theColumn".equals(columnName)) {
        System.out.println("Bingo!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ivan, be aware there are some complexities if you use an alias (SELECT col AS foo). http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43684

Comment: @JoshuaMartell, `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel` can be used if interested in getting the name as defined by the `AS` clause of the SQL query

Answer (score 19):

Try using the method [ResultSet#findColumn(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#findColumn(java.lang.String))

```
private boolean isThere(ResultSet rs, String column)
{
  try
  {
    rs.findColumn(column);
    return true;
  } catch (SQLException sqlex)
  {
    logger.debug("column doesn't exist {}", column);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It may be compared to a regular execution of Java. Bear in mind that usually bottleneck is not the Java code but the thins that are running on the other side -- the database. Most probably execution of the query and transport of data is few orders of magnitude slower than exception handling.

Comment: Link gives 404.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
rs.findColumn("theColum")
```

and check for SQLException

Comment: Yeah, easiest way I would think is to just try to retrieve the column one way or another and catch the exception.

Comment: this is generally a bad solution since you're knowingly throwing an Exception for a common case, throwing Exceptions is for rare cases and is expensive in terms of resources

Answer (score 3):

**Use the `ResultSetMetaData` class.**

```
public static boolean hasColumn(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
        if (columnName.equals(rsmd.getColumnName(x))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) object provided by the `ResultSet` object via `rs.getMetaData()`