# Test ResultSet to see if it contains a column label

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Is it possible to check a ResultSet to see if it contains a column label for the current row. I would assume that it is backed by some kind of Map, so providing an rs.contains("label") method can't be that expensive, but I can't find one in the javadoc.

The current way I'm testing for the presence of a label is:

```
BigDecimal bid;
    try {
        bid = rs.getBigDecimal("bid");
    }
    catch(final SQLException e) {
        bid = null;
    }
```

But this seems untidy to me, and will be unreadable if you want to test multiple rows in this manner.

Comment: See related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942583/how-to-check-that-a-resultset-contains-a-specifically-named-field/3942652#3942652

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use metadata that you can obtain from resultset. Use `rs.getMetaData()`, and then on metadata there are `getColumnName()` and `getColumnLabel()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/class-use/ResultSetMetaData.html) (see my related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942583/how-to-check-that-a-resultset-contains-a-specifically-named-field/3942652#3942652)). This is what I would prefer you to use. What you do is retrieve the ResultSetMetaData from the ResultSet, iterate through it and see if `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(int index)` returns the column name you've been looking for.

Alternatively, you can use [`ResultSet.findColumn()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#findColumn(java.lang.String)) to find a column within a ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Your query will already determine what columns are returned. But the ResultSetMetadata tells you what columns are present.