# JDBI ResultSetMapper: partially map row to a Class

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, jdbi, sqlresultsetmapping

When we define Mapper for a class, we have to fetch every column in sql queries in order to map with the Class in jdbc resultsetmapper

eg.

```
public class Mapper implements ResultSetMapper<MyClass>{
    public MyClass map(int index, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException{
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.setEntity1(rs.getString("column1"));
        mc.setEntity2(rs.getString("column2"));
        mc.setEntity3(rs.getString("column3"));
        return mc;
    }
}
```

For using this mapper, I have to fetch every column used in Mapper, but If I fetch only 2 columns it will throw PSQLException.

So instead of defining another Mapper for fetching 2 columns, is there any possible method to Use the same Mapper for mapping to MyClass?

Comment: have you tried using `RowMapper` ?

Comment: Post the exception's stack trace.

Comment: @pingw33n it says that "column3" is not found in resultset

Comment: @FlorescentTicker I don't think that RowMapper will work as that also use ResultSet to map to columns

Comment: So you want to fetch only columns that actually exist in the `ResultSet`?

Comment: @pingw33n yes. In some queries all columns can be present or in some queries only 2 or 1 columns can be present

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942583/how-to-check-that-a-resultset-contains-a-specifically-named-field.